# Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

This error started suddenly on the production server.
Everything works fine on local.

I am using my own authentication token based architecture.
authenticate_user is the function which checks if the current user is authenticated or not.

```
I, [2018-04-28T07:20:53.095743 #1063]  INFO -- : [af1e0a7c-41c9-4082-965a- 
3327aae9fd99] Processing by Api::V1::AnalysisController#analysis as JSON
I, [2018-04-28T07:20:53.095838 #1063]  INFO -- : [af1e0a7c-41c9-4082-965a- 
3327aae9fd99]   Parameters: {"customer_id"=>""}
I, [2018-04-28T07:20:53.098717 #1063]  INFO -- : [af1e0a7c-41c9-4082-965a- 
3327aae9fd99] [active_model_serializers] Rendered 
ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.18ms)
I, [2018-04-28T07:20:53.098997 #1063]  INFO -- : [af1e0a7c-41c9-4082-965a- 
3327aae9fd99] Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or 
redirected
I, [2018-04-28T07:20:53.099120 #1063]  INFO -- : [af1e0a7c-41c9-4082-965a- 
3327aae9fd99] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (Views: 2.8ms)
```

It is working on a diff server that i run.
The only differences between the two are 1. I'm using custom exceptions to handle errors. and rescuing them from controllers.
2. Authenitcate_user method renders directly without raising any exceptions.
3. Previously authenitcate_user was called before some method. Now there is no  only field for this one.

Authenticable Module:

```
def authenticate_user
    if current_user
      true
    else
      render json: 'some error', status: 404
    end
end
def current_user
    @user = User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization']) if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
    @user if @user && @user.token_expiry > Time.now
end
```

Controller:

```
class Api::V1::AnalysisController < ApplicationController

include Authenticable

before_action :authenticate_user
```

Comment: At least post your errors with full stack trace, and some code to show what the heck you're trying to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: can you post the relevant code that calls the failing method?

Comment: code posted @lacostenycoder

Comment: what happens if `request.headers['Authorization'].present? == false` ?

Comment: current_user value will be null.
it will return nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169982/discussion-between-ashusvirus-and-lacostenycoder).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe try this

```
def authenticate_user
  if current_user
     render json: 'success', status: 200
  else
    render json: 'error', status: 404
  end
end

def current_user
  return unless @user = User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
  @user if @user.token_expiry > Time.now
end
```

Comment: there is something that i noticed. some controller methods work. like user update. where the `before_action` has **only** attributes

Comment: if you add the `only` attribute, it will only run the `before_action` on those which you specify.  Without, it will run the hook before any action called by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, 
the issue was in the cache and cookie handling at the server.
Edited it in the CloudFront, able to catch request headers again.